# How to create a Button in the camera view in vuforia?

Tags: android, vuforia

I am using Vuforia AR sdk and want to create a button on the camera preview on the screen.

I cannot figure out where and how to add the button.

Comment: You are using Unity or normal eclipse with java and native android code?

Comment: i am using normal eclipse.

Comment: So what is the issue you are getting? It is simple to achieve it !!

Answer (score 1):

*I have edit the camera_overlay_udt.xml like this.. In my layout design i have placed back button and listview.*

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/camera_overlay_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Swipart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arcstarButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/star_button" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/favListingLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/favlist"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/overlay_bottom_bar_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/overlay_bottom_bar_separators" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/camera_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_camera_button"
            android:onClick="onCameraClick"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_button_background" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar"
        android:background="@color/overlay_bottom_bar_separators" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

*after that please Edit that ImageTargets.java class*

```
private void addOverlayView(boolean initLayout) {
    // Inflates the Overlay Layout to be displayed above the Camera View
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    mUILayouts = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.camera_overlay_udt, null, false);

    mUILayouts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // If this is the first time that the application runs then the
    // uiLayout background is set to BLACK color, will be set to
    // transparent once the SDK is initialized and camera ready to draw
    if (initLayout) {
        mUILayouts.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    // Adds the inflated layout to the view
    addContentView(mUILayouts, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // Gets a reference to the bottom navigation bar
    mBottomBar = mUILayouts.findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);

    // Gets a reference to the Camera button

    mCameraButton = mUILayouts.findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
    mCameraButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    favButton = (ImageButton) mUILayouts.findViewById(R.id.arcstarButton);
    listview = (ListView) mUILayouts.findViewById(R.id.favlist);
    backButton = (ImageButton) mUILayouts.findViewById(R.id.backButton);

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    galleryList = SendFile.getFavourites();

    if (galleryList != null) {
        gridviewAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(ImageTargets.this);

        listview.setAdapter(gridviewAdapter);
    }

    favButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (galleryList != null && galleryList.size() > 0) {

                if (listview.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ImageTargets.this, "Favourites not fond",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView,
                View paramView, int positon, long paramLong) {

            SendFile.setFavourite(galleryList.get(positon));

            Intent intent = new Intent(ImageTargets.this,
                    LoadingScreen.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("x", x_Axis);
            bundle.putInt("y", y_Axis);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });

    showDialogHandler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");

            if ((null != aResponse)) {

                // ALERT MESSAGE
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Server Response: " + aResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                showAlertDialog(aResponse);

            } else {

                // ALERT MESSAGE
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Not Got Response From Server.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        };

    };

    loadingDialogHandler.captureButtonContainer = mUILayouts
            .findViewById(R.id.camera_button);

    mUILayouts.bringToFront();
}
```

*They showing there layouts using handlers*

Answer (score 0):

Start you camera preview in a normal way. Place a layout on top of it with transparent background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/start_image_button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:src="@drawable/scan_image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In java file, you can add this layout like this:

```
private View mStartupView;
mStartupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
R.layout.startup_screen, null);

// Add it to the content view:
addContentView(mStartupView, new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

This way you will get to see your button on top of camera preview. Hope it helps

Comment: I used setcontentview() in oncreate of the imagetargets.java but the button does not show.

Comment: may be inside initApplication() function you can try to add Contentview. dont use setcontentview. Here a view already exists, so you need to add more views to the existing view. See my code where I have added the view using addContentView. This way it works.

Comment: you need to add after camera preview is created. Then only it will be seen on top of camera preview.

Comment: i added the java code at the end of the initApplication() it is not working. Can you tell me the function that i should add the java code in?

Comment: do it at the end of "case APPSTATUS_INITED" and then bring your layout to front using this "myLayout.bringToFront(); or just try to bring your layout to front in probbaly onResume() code and see

Comment: That didnt help either.

Comment: I'll make it simple for you. Your code has mUILayout implemented which is for showing loading dailog. Once vuforia engine is loaded, they dismiss the loading dialog. So, in camera_overlay layout, add a button. It should be shown then.

Comment: no it did not work either. I dont understand why it wont work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add buttons in cameraoverlay layout which is in layout folder and you can initialize buttons in initAR function which is in mainactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add the button in the camera_overlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/camera_overlay_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:text="Button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Step 2: Edit the ImageTargets.java class

```
private static final String LOGTAG = "ImageTargets";
private Button b1;
```

Step 3: Modify the initApplicationAR() function of ImageTargets.java class

```
private void initApplicationAR()
{
    // Create OpenGL ES view:
    int depthSize = 16;
    int stencilSize = 0;
    boolean translucent = Vuforia.requiresAlpha();

    mGlView = new SampleApplicationGLView(this);
    mGlView.init(translucent, depthSize, stencilSize);

    mRenderer = new ImageTargetRenderer(this, vuforiaAppSession);
    mRenderer.setTextures(mTextures);
    mGlView.setRenderer(mRenderer);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}
```

Now lay back and watch your button disappear on a click!

Answer (score -1):

Although it's a long time since the post.. yet I found one article.. wherein you can have the desired thing..

Ref: https://medium.com/nosort/adding-views-on-top-of-unityplayer-in-unityplayeractivity-e76240799c82

Solution:

Step1: Make a custom layout XML file (vuforia_widget_screen.xml). For example, button has been added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/unity_player_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/welcome" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Step 2: Make following changes in the UnityPlayerActivity.java

Replace "`setContentView(mUnityPlayer);`" with

```
setContentView(R.layout.vuforia_widget_screen);
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.unity_player_layout);
frameLayout.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView());
```

-> For anyone, who will face the issue in future. :)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks @SurajRao, I know.. but referring the link would make understand better (as the whole article is worth reading) rather than copy and paste the same thing (which should be avoided), which will obvious be redundant.

Comment: Edited my answer. @NegativeMarker Please better understand the thing that why one has done so, rather than following ethics every-time. You could have also provided the correct answer either.

Comment: @GauravGupta Just for the record: While the whole article might be readable and worth it right now it can happen as well that that might not be the case anymore in the future which is the reason stackoverflow asks for the relevant parts that answer the question to here so in case the link goes down there still is a valid answer here instead of a dead link only.